# Why my table of contents duplicate the sections?

Tags: table-of-contents, syntax

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\section{Chapter 5}
\subsection{Section 1}

\end{document}
```

I am trying to create a table of contents but it comes out like this

[image]

I only want the top part to display, I don't know why it's duplicating. Also, how can I delete the numbers on the left side of the titles? And how can I set up the page number for each section and title?

Comment: That's not a duplicate. The one at the bottom is your actual chapter and section (not part of your TOC). Add a `\clearpage` after your `\tableofcontents` to see what I mean.

Comment: @Troy Thank you, I didn't realize it... How can you disable the automatic numbering?

Comment: Just to clarify, you only want the numbering to be removed in the TOC right? You still want the numbering in the actual chapter titles and section titles?

Comment: No I don't want to see 1 next to chapter 5 and 1.1 section 1 anywhere in my pdf... sorry for bad English

Comment: It's really against the philosophy of LaTeX to do manual numbering, LaTeX is precisely there to take care of all of that nonsense for you, the automatic numbering on the left is your actual numbering, if you'd like to change the Style so that it's Chapter 1 <Title>, rather than 1 <Title> there are packages for doing that. If for some reason you're making a one-off chapter heading, I dunno, maybe you're taking notes on "Chapter 5", you can either modify the counter or just hack it with something like `\chapter*`, if you really intend to do the numbering yourself, I think you're making a mistake

Comment: And LaTeX maybe isn't the tool for you

Comment: @Au101 It looks redundant when I am providing numbering for myself. 1 Chapter 5 looks weird... I just want to get rid of these automatic numbering just to make it look nicer.

Comment: Well, you could use `\renewcommand\thesection{}` and `\renewcommand\thesubsection{}` (add them to your preamble), but I'm not sure I would recommend that either way.. There's probably a better way of doing this, that someone else might be kind enough to suggest.

Comment: Or how about setting the section counter to 5 manually using `\setcounter{section}{4}`, and naming your section without specifying the section number, e.g. `\section{Why 1+1=2}` instead of `\section{Chapter 5: Why 1+1=2}`?

Comment: @Troy, Thanks! I could make the numbering to start from 5 but still I want to make it say Chapter 5 only and Section 1 without any numbering. Because my homework notebook starts from Chapter 5 and 1 Chapter 5 sounds so weird.

Comment: It would have been useful to say that from the beginning.  You want to say `\setcounter{chapter}{4}` and then use `\chapter{Chapter Title}` and let LaTeX put the number in for you.

Comment: Also, if you're only using this section, why have a table of contents?

Comment: numbering by hand is almost always the wrong thing to do, if you want the first chapter to be 5 just put `\setcounter{chapter}{4}` at the start. In either case you should re-write your question so it is about numbering as the table of contents issue is spurious.

Answer (score 1):

Among other things, your document setup suffers from mis-using of the directives `\section` and `\subsection` to generate headers that are labeled "chapter" and "section", respectively. To reduce the confusion that will inevitably follow, you may want to switch to the `report` document class, issue the instruction `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-1}` in the preamble, and use the directives `\chapter` and `\section` to generate the corresponding headers.

```
\documentclass{report} % not 'article'
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-1}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{Chapter 5}
\section{Section 1}
\end{document}
```

If you do not want to have a page break between the table of contents and the first header, use the following code instead:

```
\documentclass{report} % not 'article'
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-1}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\begingroup
\let\clearpage\relax % locally disable '\clearpage'
\chapter{Chapter 5}
\endgroup
\section{Section 1}
\end{document}
```